# Expose SSRS Reports in websites

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I'm fairly new to the SQL Server stack, and am trying to wrap my head around how to best expose on-premise SSRS reports in websites (LAMP stack).

[URL Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155362.aspx) appears to be what I'm after, as it lets me expose a nice reporting dashboard in an iframe.

I'm stumped with authentication. The websites in question require users to authenticate (form-based), and the reports in question contain sensitive/private information (so they can't be unprotected). I need SSO (saml, oauth, etc). However, in the documentation for [Authentication with the Report Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx), I find:

> There is no native support for single sign-on technologies in Reporting Services. If you want to use a single sign-on technology, you must create a custom authentication extension.

Again, I'm new to the SQL Server stack, but I assume I'm not the first person to want to do this. The thought of writing a custom authentication extension to support SAML/OAUTH scares me - are there commercially available (and supported) extensions?

Am I barking up the wrong tree with SSRS here? Is there something else in the SQL Server stack that I should be looking at instead to achieve my goal of embedded reports?

Comment: I think this may have been answered in the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000068/sso-for-ssrs-management-site

Comment: Stumbled upon this as I am also looking for implementing SSO in SQL Server 2016 Reporting Service and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx) tells me that SSO is not supported :(